# Error! Trait method restore has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\User- laravel softdelete

Tags: laravel-5, traits, soft-delete

After using softdelete i got this error, how to fix softdelete with other trait..

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    use EntrustUserTrait {
        can as traitCan;
        hasRole as traitHasRole;
    }
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'users';
```

Answer (score 4):

finally i found my answer:

I decided to use softdelete restore instead.

```
use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    use EntrustUserTrait {
        can as traitCan;
        hasRole as traitHasRole;
    }
use SoftDeletes { SoftDeletes::restore insteadof EntrustUserTrait; }
```

or if you want to use both:

```
use SoftDeletes,EntrustUserTrait{
        SoftDeletes::restore as soft_delete_restore;
        EntrustUserTrait::restore as entrust_restore;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code and it will work:

```
public function restore()
{
    $this->restoreA();
    $this->restoreB();
}
```